# Configuration system failed to initialize exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dns

I have a small piece of code like below:

```
  private string ResolveAddress(string domain)
  {
     try
     {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(domain, @"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}"))
           return domain;
        else
           return Dns.GetHostAddresses(domain)[0].ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Error.Record("Exception caught in ResolveAddress", ex);
        return domain;
     }
  }
```

Today, for the first time I have someone complaining they cannot connect to my host.  I look in their logs and see the following exception:

```
# 6/20/2013 9:28:59 AM: Exception caught in ResolveAddress
Exception message: Configuration system failed to initialize
Exception stack trace:    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InitializeSockets()
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at NDTPresence.MainWindow.ResolveAddress(String domain)
```

Obviously if the `Dns.GetHostAddresses` call fails, they won't be able to connect to my service.  My question is why might this be happening?  The configuration file this hostname is coming out if is in the user's AppData/Roaming, but they installed it (I believe) for everyone.

Thanks.

Comment: It's pretty likely from the stack trace that the app cannot find the config file(s), so verify your beliefs :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx -> For client applications, this method retrieves a configuration file obtained by merging the application configuration file, the local user configuration file, and the roaming configuration file.

Comment: @Vivek thanks for the reply but unfortunately this is not the case.  Prior to address resolution, I have a method to load my config, which if fails produces exceptions that are logged.  In this case this method operated 100% correctly.  Also I do not explicitly use GetSection (I don't know why InitializeSockets is calling this), I have a custom XML config and a custom method to consume it.